# Spring MVC securing to get from REST only user data

Tags: java, spring, rest, api, spring-mvc

i got application web with Using Spring Boot (with Spring MVC REST API), i'm looking for method to securing data to let user get only his own.

For example, we got 4 tables, User ->  Table1 -> Table2 -> Table3 , all realation's in one to many. I'm looking for the easiest method for filter request "findAll()", when user go to /table3 there is controller which returns Table3Service.findAll() and i'm want to filter to return only data which belogns to User.

THanks for any advice!

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you need @PostFilter annotation

```
@PostFilter("hasPermission(filterObject, 'read') or hasPermission(filterObject, 'admin')")
public List<Contact> getAll();
```

and to implement methods

```
boolean hasPermission(Authentication authentication, Object targetDomainObject, Object permission);

boolean hasPermission(Authentication authentication, Serializable targetId, String targetType, Object permission);
```

Check more [here](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/3.0.x/reference/el-access.html)

Comment: isn't better to use Entity Manager and make own queries ? Or this way that you posted is better, what do you think ?

Comment: It's opinion based. In case of deep tree with lazy calls it's better to define a custom query to retrieve all in one DB request. But would be nice to add the check anyway.